# "Unable to save connector configuration. Please try again" error

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I'm trying to create a MS Teams connector which will help me in providing external entity data into MS Teams channel.
I'm following the [this blog](https://dev.to/urmade/building-a-microsoft-teams-connector-2bhp) to create new connector.

Steps perfromed -

1. Register connector on [this](https://outlook.office.com/connectors) and filled all the details.
2. Hosted my config.html file locally and expose its https link using ngrok.
3. Install the connector to Teams using Teams App Studio.
4. Installed the connector on Teams channel.

After ensuring all the above steps are completed, I installed the connector to MS Teams >  channel and on running it showed
**Error : "Unable to save "cis-connector" connector configuration. Please try again."**

Screenshot - [image]

Codebase -

config.html file -->

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <script src='https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.2/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    
    Copy your webhook URL from here to POST messages in this channel: <span id="url"></span><br><br>
    Don't forget to click on "Save" to activate your connector.
    <script>
        console.log('into script...');
        //You always have to initialize the teams SDK first before being able to call any other method
        microsoftTeams.initialize();
        //Store some settings in the configuration of the connector
        microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
            //Important when referencing your connector from somewhere else within Teams
            entityId: "sampleConn",
            //This name will be shown to channel admins under "configured connectors" - Use something that helps admins to identify this specific connection
            configName: "sampleConfig",
            //The URL to the configuration page for further config changes
            contentUrl: "https://a6b31a2cab1f.ngrok.io"
        });

        //By calling getSettings() you get (among other information) the webhook URL that you will use to POST messages into the channel
        microsoftTeams.settings.getSettings(s => {
            document.getElementById("url").innerText = s.webhookUrl;
            console.log(s);
        });
        
        //Specify what happens when the user clicks on "Save"
        microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler((saveEvent) => {
            //You have to notify Teams that the saving process was successful, otherwise the save operation will time out and display an error
            saveEvent.notifySuccess();
        });

        //This command enables the "Save" button (disabled by default)
        microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true);

        
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

index.js code -->

```
//Create a basic Node.js server
const express = require("express");
const app = express();


app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    //Send out the configuration page of the connector
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/config.html");
})

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("Server running!");
})
```

My manifest.json file -->

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.7/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.7",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "0591b282-f62f-4977-badc-fad9cff4d7e4",
  "packageName": "com.cis_connector",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Developer",
    "websiteUrl": "https://SomeValidDomainLink.com/index.html",
    "privacyUrl": "https://SomeValidDomainLink.com/privacy-policy.html",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://SomeValidDomainLink.com/terms-of-use.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "cis-connector",
    "full": "cis_connector"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "this is a cloud cost alerter",
    "full": "the connector will trigger the app and send daily aws cost spends"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "connectors": [
    {
      "connectorId": "0e9102ad-c7cf-4194-a292-e00f175c2724",
      "configurationUrl": "https://a6b31a2cab1f.ngrok.io/",
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "a6b31a2cab1f.ngrok.io"
  ]
}
```

Question - The above steps are pretty straight forward still the MS Teams connector is shwoing error. May I know what is going wrong ?

Comment: Could you please confirm if you have added the ngrok in valid domains of your connector in connector dashboard?